# jqgrid | Automatically reduce the height of edit/add grid form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Does anyone have experience with jqgrid 'editGridRow' form reducing automatically. 
I've used the 'editGridRow' to add and edit the columns on website and it shows well. However,
I found something weird happen. The grid form reduces automatically if the both 'add' and 'edit' navbuttons are clicked alternately and continuously. 
Here is the part of my code below.

```
 .jqGrid("navButtonAdd", pager_selector, {
                    caption: 'Add',
                    buttonicon: 'icon-pencil gray',
                    onClickButton: function() {
                        jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{
                            addCaption : "Add Blacklist Card",
                            width : 450,
                            //resize : true,
                            reloadAfterSubmit:true,
                            closeAfterAdd:true,
                            closeAfterEdit: true,
                            beforeInitData:setAddInit('add'),
                            beforeShowForm : function(form){
                                /*//방법1
                                $.get('/jqGrid/getblistcardList/?m_type=blist', function(data,status){
                                    var $grid = $('#CARD_NUMBER').val(data);
                                });
                                // var $grid = $('#CORPORATE_ID').val('as3fi8811sd');*/
                            },
                            afterSubmit: function(res, data) {
                                setEnd('add');
                                //alert('data : '+data);
                                if(res.responseText == "success") {
                                    //alert('저장 되었습니다.');
                                } else {
                                    //alert('저장에 실패했습니다.');
                                }
                                return ['success','message','new_id'];
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    position:"last",
                    title : "Add Blacklist Card"
                })
                .jqGrid("navButtonAdd", pager_selector, {
                    caption: 'Edit',
                    buttonicon: 'icon-edit blue',
                    onClickButton: function() {
                        //alert('Editing Row');
                        var gr = jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                        if( gr != null ) jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,{
                            editCaption : "Edit Blacklist Card",
                            width : 450,
                            reloadAfterSubmit:true,
                            closeAfterEdit: true,
                            beforeInitData:setAddInit('edit'),
                            beforeShowForm: setEditeForm,
                            afterSubmit: function(res, data) {
                                setEnd('edit');
                                if(res.responseText == "success") {
                                    //alert('Edit Completely');
                                } else {
                                    // alert('Edit Fail');
                                }
                                return ['success','message','new_id'];
                            }
                        });
                        else alert("Please Select Row");
                    },
                    position:"last",
                    title : "Edit Blacklist Card"
                })
```

I wonder if the height attribute is set essentially. How can i fix this?
Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems me a bug in jqGrid 4.6. As a workaround I suggest to use the following `onInitializeForm`:

```
onInitializeForm: function ($form) {
    $form.css({height: "auto"});
    $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").css({height: "auto"});
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/heightOfFormEdit.htm).

In the same way you can set both `height` and `width` to `"auto"`:

```
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.edit, {
    beforeInitData: function () {
        $("#editmod" + this.id).remove();
    },
    onInitializeForm: function ($form) {
        $form.css({height: "auto", width: "auto"});
        $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").css({height: "auto", width: "auto"});
    },
    width: "auto"
});
```

see [one more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/heightOfFormEdit1.htm).

**UPDATED**: The bug seems be fixed in jqGrid 4.7. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/heightOfFormEdit0.htm) which uses 4.6 and to reproduce the problem one need just open edit form, close it and to open it one more time. [The next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/heightOfFormEdit0_fix46.htm) uses the fix with I suggested in my answer. [One more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/heightOfFormEdit0_fix47.htm) use no fix and it uses jqGrid 4.7. One can see that the described above problem not exist here.

Comment: sorry for late reply. It worked very well! Thank you so much.